# Problem "Exception: Gradle task assemble Debug failed with exit code 1"

Tags: flutter

[image]

I have a problem since I updated Flutter, but I also checked with `flutter doctor` and everything is OK.
Can anyone help me fix this problem, please?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Looks like you have installed the flutter and did not setup it correctly. post the `flultter doctor` result too.

Comment: Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.1237], locale th-TH)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[√] VS Code (version 1.60.1)
[√] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!

Comment: Delete `pubspec.lock` file and then install all packages by doing `flutter pub get`.